# Python simple socket client/server using asyncio

Tags: python, sockets, python-asyncio

I would like to re-implement my code using asyncio coroutines instead of multi-threading.

server.py

```
def handle_client(client):
    request = None
    while request != 'quit':
        request = client.recv(255).decode('utf8')
        response = cmd.run(request)
        client.send(response.encode('utf8'))
    client.close()

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('localhost', 15555))
server.listen(8)

try:
    while True:
        client, _ = server.accept()
        threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client,)).start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.close()
```

client.py

```
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.connect(('localhost', 15555))
request = None

try:
    while request != 'quit':
        request = input('>> ')
        if request:
            server.send(request.encode('utf8'))
            response = server.recv(255).decode('utf8')
            print(response)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.close()
```

I know there are some appropriate asynchronous network librairies to do that. But I just want to only use asyncio core library on this case in order to have a better understanding of it.

It would have been so nice to only add async keyword before handle client definition... Here a piece of code which seems to work, but I'm still confused about the implementation.

asyncio_server.py

```
def handle_client(client):
    request = None
    while request != 'quit':
        request = client.recv(255).decode('utf8')
        response = cmd.run(request)
        client.send(response.encode('utf8'))
    client.close()

def run_server(server):
    client, _ = server.accept()
    handle_client(client)

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('localhost', 15555))
server.listen(8)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.async(run_server(server))
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.close()
```

How adapt this in the best way and using async await keywords.

Comment: Have you gone through some manner of tutorial entirely focused on `asyncio` yet?  It may be more prudent to do that first, instead of translating something you already have working.  I would recommend [this](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/07/26/python-3-an-intro-to-asyncio/) to start you off.

Comment: I have updated the question. As I am still confused about the asyncio lib, I think this use case may be relevant for a better understanding.

Comment: If you are still confused about asyncio (it's indeed a mess of futures, tasks and coroutines) and want to avoid threads, you can try `gevent` which is a well established coroutine library or, imo the best option, rely on the operating system's `select` function. Here is the Python 3 [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html?highlight=select#module-select) and a quick tutorial [Wait for IO Efficiently](https://pymotw.com/2/select/)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The closest literal translation of the threading code would create the socket as before, make it non-blocking, and use `asyncio` [low-level socket operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#working-with-socket-objects-directly) to implement the server. Here is an example, sticking to the more relevant server part (the client is single-threaded and likely fine as-is):

```
import asyncio, socket

async def handle_client(client):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    request = None
    while request != 'quit':
        request = (await loop.sock_recv(client, 255)).decode('utf8')
        response = str(eval(request)) + '\n'
        await loop.sock_sendall(client, response.encode('utf8'))
    client.close()

async def run_server():
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind(('localhost', 15555))
    server.listen(8)
    server.setblocking(False)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    while True:
        client, _ = await loop.sock_accept(server)
        loop.create_task(handle_client(client))

asyncio.run(run_server())
```

The above works, but is not the intended way to use `asyncio`. It requires precisely matching the use of the `socket` API to the expectations of asyncio, such as the `setblocking()` call. There is no buffering out-of-the-box, so something as simple as reading a line from the client becomes a tiresome chore. This API level is really only intended for implementers of alternative event loops, which would provide *their* implementation of `sock_recv`, `sock_sendall`, etc.

Asyncio's public API provides two abstraction layers intended for consumption: the lower-level [transport/protocol layer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html) modeled after Twisted, and the higher-level [streams layer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html). In new code, you almost certainly want to use the streams API, i.e. call [`asyncio.start_server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.start_server) and avoid raw sockets. That significantly reduces the line count:

```
import asyncio

async def handle_client(reader, writer):
    request = None
    while request != 'quit':
        request = (await reader.read(255)).decode('utf8')
        response = str(eval(request)) + '\n'
        writer.write(response.encode('utf8'))
        await writer.drain()
    writer.close()

async def run_server():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_client, 'localhost', 15555)
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(run_server())
```

Comment: It works so fine, even if I'm still confused about why asynchronous and sockets seem to be such intricated to be wrapped in the same library...

Comment: @srjjio Network (socket) programming constitutes a huge chunk of the _motivation_ for needing asynchronous IO in the first place. An asyncio library that didn't provide support for sockets wouldn't be of much use.

Comment: I see, thank you very much for your help @user4815162342

Comment: Does this keep a socket open for each *client* or is a new socket created for each request/response?

Comment: Should there be a `await writer.drain()` following the `writer.write()` call? [See here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamWriter.write).

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Yes, good catch. As written, the code will work - writes will be flushed out by the event loop - but they will not be subject to backpressure, opening a potential [memory leak](https://vorpus.org/blog/some-thoughts-on-asynchronous-api-design-in-a-post-asyncawait-world/#bug-1-backpressure). In the first snippet the backpressure is inherent to `sock_sendall` which will suspend the coroutine until the OS actually accepts the write, thus incorporating the equivalent of `StreamWriter.drain`.

Comment: Do you know if there's any way to read/write sockets in "parallel" using `asyncio`? I'd like to send read data to an input queue and process it. In a separate thread/process, processed results should be pulled out of an output queue and written to the socket.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Sure, create two tasks and write to separate streams. But this sounds like a separate question...

Comment: Should that last line of code be "loop.run_until_complete(run_server)" instead of "loop.run_until_complete(run_server())"?

Comment: @DevPlayer No, `run_server` is a coroutine function, and `run_until_complete` expects an awaitable. To create an awaitable, you have to actually call the coroutine function. This is analogous to functions expecting an iterable - you can't just pass them a generator function, you have to actually *call* the generator to get an iterable.

Comment: This server will be running on its own, being very passive. Can I inject a message to be sent to any client (and awaiting the client's response) in the server? I need to tell a client if something happened in the server. Still new to this async thing in Python, but I'm familiar with it in JavaScript and experienced in C#.

Comment: @ygoe That sounds like material for a new question. When asking it, please be sure to elaborate on what precisely you mean by "inject message to be sent to any client" (e.g. how you expect to deal with clients that are in the middle of receiving a message).

Answer (score 12):

I have read the answers and comments above, trying to figure out how to use the `asyncio` lib for sockets.
As it often happens with Python, the official documentation along with the examples is the best source of useful information.
I got understanding of [`Transports and Protocols`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#protocols) (low-level API), and [`Streams`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html) (high-level API) from the examples presented in the end of the support article.

For example, TCP Echo Server:

```
import asyncio


class EchoServerProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        peername = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        print('Connection from {}'.format(peername))
        self.transport = transport

    def data_received(self, data):
        message = data.decode()
        print('Data received: {!r}'.format(message))

        print('Send: {!r}'.format(message))
        self.transport.write(data)

        print('Close the client socket')
        self.transport.close()


async def main():
    # Get a reference to the event loop as we plan to use
    # low-level APIs.
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    server = await loop.create_server(
        lambda: EchoServerProtocol(),
        '127.0.0.1', 8888)

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


asyncio.run(main())
```

and TCP Echo Client:

```
import asyncio


class EchoClientProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, message, on_con_lost):
        self.message = message
        self.on_con_lost = on_con_lost

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        transport.write(self.message.encode())
        print('Data sent: {!r}'.format(self.message))

    def data_received(self, data):
        print('Data received: {!r}'.format(data.decode()))

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        print('The server closed the connection')
        self.on_con_lost.set_result(True)


async def main():
    # Get a reference to the event loop as we plan to use
    # low-level APIs.
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    on_con_lost = loop.create_future()
    message = 'Hello World!'

    transport, protocol = await loop.create_connection(
        lambda: EchoClientProtocol(message, on_con_lost),
        '127.0.0.1', 8888)

    # Wait until the protocol signals that the connection
    # is lost and close the transport.
    try:
        await on_con_lost
    finally:
        transport.close()


asyncio.run(main())
```

Hope it help someone searching for simple explanation of `asyncio`.

Comment: connection closed when using telnet client connect to this echo server?

Comment: Note that the pasted examples are certainly **not** a good example of using asyncio, as they show the older callback-based style, rather than async/await which is easier to use and much more represented nowadays (in python as well in other languages).