# asyncio with multiple methods in micropython

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, micropython

When I run the following code, it runs and print ("Listening, connect your APP to http://192.168.4.1:8080/") and waiting request as web server. During the web server mode, I want the LED to blink that's why I have applied `asyncio`.

However, unless it receives any request (which activates `While True:` loop in web server), LED does not respond. I have tried many ways but I could not find a way to toggle of LED during web server mode. You can see the comment regarding to `await asyncio.sleep(20)` in the code below:

```
import uasyncio as asyncio
from machine import Pin
import time

LED_PIN = 13
led = Pin(LED_PIN, Pin.OUT, value=1)

async def toggle():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep_ms(500)
        led.value(not led.value()) # toggling        

async def webServer(ipAddress):
    s = socket.socket()
    ai = socket.getaddrinfo(ipAddress, 8080)
    print("Bind address info:", ai)
    addr = ai[0][-1]
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind(addr)
    s.listen(2)
    print("Listening, connect your APP to http://%s:8080/" % ipAddress)

    counter = 0
    # await asyncio.sleep(20) # !! if i applied await here, LED toggling 20 secs but web server does not accept any request because "while True" below is not activated during 20 secs.
    while True:
        res = s.accept()
        client_sock = res[0]
        client_addr = res[1]
        print("Client address:", client_addr)
        print("Client socket:", client_sock)

        req = client_sock.recv(1024)
        print("Payload: %s" % req.decode())
        client_sock.send(CONTENT % counter)
        client_sock.close()
        counter += 1
        print()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(toggle())
loop.create_task(webServer('192.168.4.1'))
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: I want to know what is your embedded board name? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `webServer` async function is not really async because it uses *blocking IO*. At a minimum you need to set the socket to non-blocking mode and use the socket operations [provided by asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#low-level-socket-operations), or even better you should use [`asyncio.start_server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.start_server) to implement an asynchronous network server.

See the asyncio documentation or e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48507121/1600898) for examples.

Comment: `loop.create_task(asyncio.start_server(handle_client, (ap_if.ifconfig()[0]), 8080)) & async def handle_client(reader, writer)` is solved the issue, Thanks. Only one issue, it is not overwriting the open connection. It enters web server mode only after reset. In sockets method, `s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` was solving the issue, but i could not find a way in asyncio, how it can be corrected.

Comment: @Sunrise17 Try passing `reuse_addr=True` to `start_server`. (This should be the default under POSIX OS-es.)

Comment: After 5 or 6 request as following below, from mobile App(URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)) to asyncio server installed on esp8266, server has timed out after a while. `Request path: /
Content Length: 22
Request headers: Host: 0.0.0.0:10000
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Chroma
Accept-Language: 
Content-Length: 22
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Request payload: {"COLOR":[255,21,226]}`

Comment: @Sunrise17 Maybe you should ask a different question about this problem, with a minimal example etc...

Comment: It was related to asyncio server, in any case, i will open a new question about that.