# Python sockets server and client in one script

Tags: python, sockets, python-asyncio

I have a seemingly simple task that I can't quite wrap my brains around.
Here is what I need to do. Using socket module, start a server, use a client to start a connection, stop the server, return connection data - all in one script. I can do it when I run the two from two terminals but I need to put both server and client code in one script for automation. My problem is that socket.accept() is a blocking call and the script hangs before I can invoke the client. Tried playing with socket.setblocking(False) but it still blocks. I intuitively feel that I can accomplish this with asyncio module, but I have no experience with it and the examples I've seen don't seem to fit my task. Thanks much.

Comment: You could try using threads. One for the server and oner for the client. [thrading module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html). In short threads are like programs that run independet

Answer (score 2):

> I need to put both server and client code in one script for automation. My problem is that `socket.accept()` is a blocking call and the script hangs before I can invoke the client. [...] I intuitively feel that I can accomplish this with asyncio module

Asyncio indeed makes it easy to start several tasks "in the background" (see [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task)) or "in parallel" (see [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather)).

In fact, since the [`start_server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.start_server) API runs the server "in the background" to begin with (sort of how a server forks to daemonize itself, and you don't have to add `&` when starting it from a shell), you don't even need to do anything special to start the client and the server in parallel - just start the server, await the client coroutine, and stop the server.

As an example, starting with the echo client/server examples from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#streams), I've quickly arrived to something like this:

```
import asyncio

async def connect():
    print('connecting...')
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 8888)
    writer.write(b'hello world')
    data = await reader.read(100)
    assert data == b'hello world'
    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()
    print('closed connection')
    return data

async def handle_client(reader, writer):
    print('incoming connection')
    while True:
        data = await reader.read(100)
        if data == b'':
            break
        writer.write(data)
        await writer.drain()
    print('incoming connection closed')

async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_client, '127.0.0.1', 8888)
    print('server now set up')
    await connect()
    server.close()
    await server.wait_closed()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: My client is on a different host and I can't use the native start_server because I am testing ssl sockets, so I need the socket and the ssl context. I am looking at your other example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506460/python-simple-socket-client-server-using-asyncio, and it allows to use a socket, but what about the client being on a different host, would it still be possible to handle with asyncio? Thanks much.

Comment: @postoronnim `start_server` supports SSL (see the [ssl keyword argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.start_server), so that shouldn't be a problem. I don't understand the part about "client being on a different host", as it seems to run counter to the requirement of server and client "being in one script" and isn't mentioned in the question at all.

Comment: A console connection to the client already exists, so whenever I need to I can make a call to the client, e.g. start_tls_session().

Comment: @postoronnim What is a "console connection to the client"? The answer shows how to set up a server and connect to it in a single script, which was the goal presented in the question. If your goal is something else, please **edit the question** and describe it, so that your question can actually be answered.