# Attempting To Connect To a Website Returns "ConnectionResetError: [WinError 64] The specified network name is no longer available"

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, python-asyncio

I am trying to connect to the Discord API using raw sockets. To improve performance and concurrency, I've decided to use `asyncio`. However, it has been much less cooperative than the socket module by itself. `sock_connect` cannot take in a url for the address, so I had to look up Discord's IP (which I'm not even positive is correct).

```py
import socket
import asyncio
import ssl

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

HOST = "162.159.138.232" # Previously was `discord.com`, but that raised...
# `OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied` in `sock_connect`
PORT = 443 # HTTPS port

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=HOST)
s_sock.setblocking(False)


async def make_connection():
    await loop.sock_connect(s_sock, (HOST, PORT))
    await loop.sock_sendall(s_sock, b'''GET /api/v6/users/@me/guilds HTTP/1.0\r 
    Host: discord.com\r
    User-Agent: PyDisc ($www.hi.com, $0.0.1)\r
    Authorization: Bot tokentokentoken\r
    \r\n''')
    f = await loop.sock_recv(s_sock, 4096)
    print(f)
loop.run_until_complete(make_connection())
```

My code now just hangs for several seconds and then responds with this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 453, in finish_recv
    return ov.getresult()
OSError: [WinError 64] The specified network name is no longer available

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/User/Desktop/VS Code/client.py", line 26, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(make_connection())
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "c:/Users/User/Desktop/VS Code/client.py", line 24, in make_connection
    f = await loop.sock_recv(s_sock, 4096)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 693, in sock_recv
    return await self._proactor.recv(sock, n)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 808, in _poll
    value = callback(transferred, key, ov)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 457, in finish_recv
    raise ConnectionResetError(*exc.args)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 64] The specified network name is no longer available
```

I have  tested this code by locally spawning a `TCP` server (using the `socketserver` module) and it worked as expected. I used my local IP address for that and the port 9999. It is also worth noting that this worked when I didn't use `asyncio`.

If you are suspicious that I have the wrong IP address for the discord website, here is where I got it (From command prompt):

```
C:\Users\User>ping discord.com

Pinging discord.com [162.159.138.232] with 32 bytes of data:
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506460/python-simple-socket-client-server-using-asyncio#48507121 help you?

Comment: You almost certainly want to use [`asyncio.open_connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.open_connection) with the `ssl=True` flag. As pointed out in the answer linked by dirn (which covers the server side), the socket functions provided by the event loop are meant as basis for building higher-level streaming transactions, not something you'd want to use directly. More importantly, SSL complicates things immensely, so a "literal" translation as given in that answer is not possible, or would contain much more code.