# How would I open and run a python program on a raspberry pi from a main python program on a windows pc?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, wireless, serial-communication

I am running a main python program on a Windows PC that is hooked to equipment that cannot be ran on an Raspberry pi. At a certain point in the main program, I want to call/execute a Rpi program to run. I need the GPIO pins from the Rpi to turn on a relay/s. Is there a way to wirelessly(or serially) open and run the program on the raspberry pi from the main program already running on the Windows PC?

Maybe I am not thinking of something, is there an easier and just as cheap solution to turn on a relay from the Windows PC program?

Any points in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ssh` can be given a program to execute on the remote host. You could, from the PC, run `ssh` with the path of the second program to execute on the Pi.

Comment: You could add a part of the Rpi program to act as a client listening for commands from server code hosted on the PC.

This can be achieved in many ways, e.g. HTTP, sockets, a serial connection, file transfer protocols, etc.

Maybe [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506460/python-simple-socket-client-server-using-asyncio) can help you get started.

Comment: If you want to do it wirelessly, you can use an nRF24L01+ 2.4GHz transceiver to send a signal to the Pi.

Comment: you could simply use a usb interface relay such as -- https://www.amazon.com/SMAKN%C2%AE-LCUS-1-module-intelligent-control/dp/B01CN7E0RQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with [Remote GPIO](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/remote_gpio.html) which is all documented at that link. However, the gist of it is pretty simple as follows.

---

On the Raspberry Pi, run these steps:

- `sudo apt install pigpio`
- `sudo raspi-config` and enable *"Remote GPIO"*
- `sudo systemctl enable pigpiod`

---

On the Windows PC, run these steps:

- `pip install gpiozero pigpio`
- Assuming your RaspberryPi has IP address 192.168.1.3, run `PIGPIO_ADDR=192.168.1.3 python3 YourScript.py`

---

Your script on Windows PC would then look like this:

```
from gpiozero import LED
from time import sleep

red = LED(17)

while True:
    red.on()
    sleep(1)
    red.off()
    sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on security requirements.  Assuming that the Desktop PC and raspberry pi are on the same network, you could create an HTTP REST endpoint on the pi, you could use flask or fastapi for this.  then call that from the app running on the desktop. for help with flask see https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/ if you are familiar with python flask is fairly simple to get started with.