# TCP connection and parallel running processes

Tags: python, tcp, parallel-processing

My aim is to talk to a raspberry via a TCP socket and based on certain commands the raspberry should control some GPIOs.

For now my first goal is to start a LED blinking via one command sent by the client...

I have already written the script for the daemon receiving the data from a client (telnet on LINUX OS), which is working pretty well so far. :)

I can also start the LED blinking, BUT I haven't managed to stop it yet, because I am stuck in the "blinking loop".

Of course I read about asynchronous programing, multiprocessing or threading, but nothing did work for my problem... (or I just don`t know how to use it ^^)

Does anyone have a solution for this problem or have you already done a similar project?

THANK U!

Comment: IMHO it would be simpler to use PIGPIO, like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/67867920/2836621

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.