# Problem in connecting two different devices using sockets in Python

Tags: python, python-sockets

I want to connect my two different devices using sockets library in Python. Both my devices are connected to the same Internet connection. I tried to use the sockets library to establish the connection. I ran the server script on one device and the client script on another device and tried to establish a connection. But the connection was not established. Is there a problem in my code or there is some other issue?

server.py:-

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 5050))

print("Server Starting")
sock.listen()

while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print("New connection " + str(addr))
```

client.py:-

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('Server IP address', 5050))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python simple socket client/server using asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506460/python-simple-socket-client-server-using-asyncio)

Comment: Also what does `socket.gethostname()` return? It should be the IP you are trying you connect to, or '0.0.0.0' (which it won't be, but you could put it manually there).

Comment: The 'gethostname' function in socket returns the name of the device. And the 'gethostbyname' returns the ip address of the host name. So, socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) will return the ip address of my device

Comment: This link: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506460/python-simple-socket-client-server-using-asyncio" did not answer my question. My question was that, is there a problem in my code or there is some other issue that is causing the problem of the connection?