# In python 3, is it possible to convert this client-server threaded code to client-server asyncio code?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I have a simple client server routine that uses threading which I am trying to convert to asyncio as an exercise for learning asyncio:

```
# This threading code works as expected (see asyncio code below for what does't work)
import socket
from _thread import start_new_thread
import threading
import time

def handle_client(conn):
    count=0
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        count += 1
        reply = f"hello {count}, {data}"
        conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
    conn.close()

def server_program():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5000

    server_socket = socket.socket()
    try:
        server_socket.bind((host,port))
    except socket.error as e:
        print(str(e))
    server_socket.listen(5)
    while True:
        conn, address = server_socket.accept()
        start_new_thread(handle_client, (conn,))
    server_socket.close()


def client_program(greeting):
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5000

    client_socket = socket.socket()
    message = f"{greeting}"
    count=0
    try:
        client_socket.connect((host,port))
    except socket.error as e:
 print(str(e))
        return
    while True:
        client_socket.send(str.encode(message))
        count += 1
        message = f"{greeting} {count}"
        response = client_socket.recv(1024)
        print(response.decode('utf-8'))
        time.sleep(2)
    client_socket.close()


def main():
    x1 = threading.Thread(target=server_program, args=())
    x2 = threading.Thread(target=client_program, args=("howdy",))
    x3 = threading.Thread(target=client_program, args=("hi",))
    x1.start()
    x2.start()
    x3.start()
    x1.join()
    x2.join()
    x3.join()
    print("All threads have finished running")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It's not working.  Here's what I came up with.

```
import asyncio
import socket
import time

async def handle_client(conn, loop):
    count = 0
    while True:
        data = await loop.sock_recv(conn, 1024).decode('utf-8')
        count += 1
        reply = f"hello {count}, {data}"
        conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
    conn.close()

async def server_program(loop):
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5000

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        server_socket.bind((host,port))
    except socket.error as e:
        print(str(e))
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.setblocking(False)
    server_socket.listen(10)
    while True:
        print("server_program code gets to here...")
        conn, addr = await loop.sock_accept(server_socket)
        # server_program never gets here.  It blocks.  
        loop.create_task(handle_client(conn, loop))
    server_socket.close()


async def client_program(greeting, loop):
    print("client_program")
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5000

    client_socket = socket.socket()
 message = f"{greeting}"
    count=0
    try:
        client_socket.connect((host,port))
    except socket.error as e:
        print(str(e))
        return
    while True:
        count += 1
        message = f"{greeting} {count}"
        print("client_program code gets here")
        response = await loop.sock_recv(client_socket, 1024)
        # Client_program never gets here.  It blocks.
        print(response.decode('utf-8'))
        time.sleep(2)
    client_socket.close()


async def main(loop):
    loop.create_task(server_program(loop))
    loop.create_task(client_program("howdy", loop))
    loop.create_task(client_program("hi", loop))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
        print("All threads have finished running")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

Is it possible to run this client server application using asyncio?  If so, what can be changed to make the asyncio code work the same as the threaded code?

Comment: What *specifically* are you asking here? Does the new code work? Does it fail? What's wrong about it?

Comment: The asyncio code doesn't work.  It blocks.  The server code blocks at sock_accept.  The client code blocks at sock_recv.  The threading code works as expected.

Comment: I am trying to understand how to implement the above threaded code in asyncio.  I am trying to get a client-server app working in asyncio.  The threading code works.  The asyncio code does not.

Comment: Do not use `time.sleep` in async code. I don't know if this is the only problem here, but it's a big one.

Comment: You can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48507121/1600898) for inspiration. Note in particular that you probably want to use asyncio streams rather than raw sockets.