# Replace 'While-True'-Loop with something more efficient

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, python-asyncio

### Problem

It's very common for beginners to solve IO waiting while concurrent processing in an similar way like here:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""Loop example."""

from time import sleep

WAITING: bool = True
COUNTER: int = 10


def process() -> None:
    """Non-blocking routine, that needs to be invoked periodically."""
    global COUNTER  # pylint: disable=global-statement
    print(f"Done in {COUNTER}.")
    COUNTER -= 1
    sleep(1)
    # Mimicking incoming IO callback
    if COUNTER <= 0:
        event()


def event() -> None:
    """Incoming IO callback routine."""
    global WAITING  # pylint: disable=global-statement
    WAITING = False


try:
    while WAITING:
        process()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Canceled.")
```

Possible applications might be servers, what are listening for incomming messages, while still processing some other internal stuff.

### Possible Solution 1

**Threading** might in some cases a good solution.
But after some research it seems that threading adds a lot of overheading for the communcation between the threads.
One example for this might be the 'Warning' [in the `osc4py3` package documentation below the headline 'No thread'](https://osc4py3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userdoc.html#no-thread).
Also i have read somewhere the thumb rule, that 'Threading suits not for slow IO' (sorry, lost the source of this rule).

### Possible Solution 2

**Asynchronous processing** (with the `asyncio` package) might be another solution.
Especially because the ominous thumb rule also says that 'For slow IO is `asyncio` efficient'.

### What i tried

So i tried to rewrite this example with `asyncio` but failed completely, even after reading about `Tasks`, `Futures` and `Awaitable`s in general in the Python `asyncio` documentation.
My problem was to solve the **perodically** (instead of one time) call while waiting.
Of course there are infinite loops possible, but all examples i found in the internet are still using 'While-True'-Loops what does not look like an improvement to me.
For example this snippet:

```py
import asyncio

async def work():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("Task Executed")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    asyncio.ensure_future(work())
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    print("Closing Loop")
    loop.close()
```

*Source: https://tutorialedge.net/python/concurrency/asyncio-event-loops-tutorial/#the-run_forever-method*

### What i want

To know the most elegant and efficient way of rewriting these stupid general 'While-True'-Loop from my first example code.
If my 'While-True'-Loop is still the best way to solve it (beside my `global` variables), then it's also okay to me.
I just want to improve my code, if possible.

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: You are misinformed about a couple of things.  There is nothing wrong with using threads for slow I/O processes, and I think you will find that the asyncio library often uses threads internally.  There is also nothing wrong - or stupid - with `while True:` loops if that's what the logic of your program dictates.  However, it may be inefficient to wait for events using hard-coded time delays (asyncio.sleep or time.sleep) instead of using queues, or Event or Condition objects.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is some kind of [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) operation and is similar to [busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting). You should rarely rely on those methods as they can incur a serious performance penalty if used incorrectly. Instead, you should rely on concurrency primitives provided by the OS of a concurrency library.

As said in a comment, you could rely on a condition or an event (and more broadly on mutexes) to schedule some come to run after an event occurs. For I/O operations you can also rely on low-level OS facilities such as [select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(Unix)), [poll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poll_(Unix)) and signals/interruptions.

> Possible applications might be servers, what are listening for
> incomming messages, while still processing some other internal stuff.

For such use cases you should really use a dedicated library to do that efficiently. For instance, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506460/python-simple-socket-client-server-using-asyncio) is an example of a minimal server developed with AsyncIO's low-level socket operations. Internally, AsyncIO probably uses the `select` system call and exposes a friendly interface with `async-await`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `asyncio`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""Asyncronous loop example."""

from typing import Callable
from asyncio import Event, get_event_loop


DONE = Event()


def callback():
    """Incoming IO callback routine."""
    DONE.set()


def process():
    """Non-blocking routine, that needs to be invoked periodically."""
    print('Test.')


try:
    loop = get_event_loop()
    run: Callable = lambda loop, processing: (
        processing(),
        loop.call_soon(run, loop, processing)
    )
    loop.call_soon(run, loop, process)
    loop.call_later(1, callback)  # Mimicking incoming IO callback after 1 sec
    loop.run_until_complete(DONE.wait())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Canceled.")
finally:
    loop.close()
    print("Bye.")
```